# How to download a web page content to a text file exactly as the web page is?

Tags: grep, lynx

I am trying to extract some info from a web page. Imagine you have a name given to you (Northcentral Siberia, Russia) and want to extract whole line containing this name from a web page. To handle this, I downloaded the web page (`https://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/list.php`) into a text file using lynx command (`lynx --dump "https://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/list.php" > text.txt`) and tried to grep the line containing the name "Northcentral Siberia, Russia". the following line shows the info in the web page which all are in a row:

```
2018-05-27 04:27:17 4.8 60.07°N 128.42°E    10  A       Northcentral Siberia, Russia
```

But when I downloaded the web page into a text file the above line breaks into two lines as follows:

```
2018-05-27 04:27:17 4.8 60.07°N 128.42°E    10  A   Northcentral 
Siberia, Russia
```

In this case, if I try to extract this line using its full name (Northcentral Siberia, Russia) and grep, it will fail. How can I deal with that?

Comment: post the crucial **raw** fragment from the web page to process

Comment: Your question is worded unclearly.  You’re not talking about *order,* you’re talking about logical units of text being fragmented across lines. P.S. This problem is probably bigger than you realize.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my nature language! I edited my question hope to be more clear

Comment: As it looks like that for me, does the location name contain a line break? In that case would it be possible to clean the data before writing the file or afterwards?

Comment: I don't think so! This case happens only for long lines. I added the web page link to be more clear ...

Comment: It may be better to download the raw html. In any case we can not tell you what you are doing wrong, because you have not shown us what you have done.

Comment: Any ideas about this? If downloading the web page wont work so what can I do to extract a line from a web page with only knowing a name within that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because when you use the `-dump` option to `lynx` it assumes that your "screen" is 80 columns wide, and the table formatting, etc of the webpage causes that to wrap.

Add in a `-width` argument and it should work -

`lynx -width=200 -dump "https://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/list.php" > text.txt`

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. problem solved :)